# Auto import CSV into existing Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, csv

I understand how to upload and convert CSV files to Google Sheets -- but how can I set up an automatic upload of all new data from a CSV file into an existing sheet?

I have a CSV file that lives on my hard drive. Anytime a new order for our company comes through, the new order data is dumped into that CSV file. Then, we have a tracking database that lives in Google Sheets, which I would love to automatically add rows with the new data every time the CSV file changes. Or, at the least, update automatically with new info once a day or something.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could Google Apps Script, the Google Sheets API or G Suite Document Editor add-on to automate tasks on Google Sheets.

To ask for an add-on recommendation please post a question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

To use Google Apps Script, please start reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

To learn about the Google Sheets API, please reas https://developers.google.com/sheets.

It's worth to note that Google Apps Script or an add-on can't access a local file so first you have to someway upload that file to the cloud (Google Drive, or something like that).